# Moving carousel indicators below the images

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I use react-bootstrap to make the carousel, and I want to move the caption and indicators below the image.
The caption part is simple, since I just needed to apply the code below as a className.

```
carouselCaption: {
    position: 'relative',
    left: 'auto',
    right: 'auto'
}
```

Problem appears with indicators, since I don't have direct access to them in code, like I do with `<Carousel.Item>` 
So here's my question, how would I go about doing it? There is quite a lot of answers for bootstrap, but I haven't found a helpful one for react-bootstrap

Comment: Use `.carousel-indicators` class to add some style to indicators.

Comment: Thing is, I'm using Material-UI primarily in this project, and I want to keep their way of styling - the one with Hook API.

Comment: Also, `position: 'relative'` doesn't change it the way it does with text

Comment: Looking for the same in vanilla Bootstrap 5, and so far nothing. The position:relative effectively kills adjusting margins and padding via CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 default Carousel: How to move indicators down and outside of slide container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207487/bootstrap-3-default-carousel-how-to-move-indicators-down-and-outside-of-slide-c)